# psql query or function that updates a column in sequential order

Tags: mysql, psql

I have a table "students" which is like below:

```
Name    | Number
--------+-------
john    | 1  
Jessy   | 2  
darine  | 3  
Prince  | 5  
queeny  | 7
```

After the update the table should be as below:

```
Name    | Number
--------+-------
john    | 1  
Jessy   | 2  
darine  | 3  
Prince  | 4  
queeny  | 5
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` clause? What have you tried? Please share your code. It is a simple sorting task

Comment: update Students set Number = nextval('number_sequence'); but out put is not as expected

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Students ORDER BY  Number ASC`

Comment: I want to be update the column in the sequential order

Comment: Tables do not have an order, so the order you insert the data does not really matter. The only way to guarantee the order of a query is to use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: which database do you use?

Answer (score 0):

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY number;
  name  | number 
--------+--------
 john   |      1
 jessy  |      2
 darine |      3
 prince |      5
 queeny |      7

postgres=# SELECT name, number, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY number) FROM foo;
  name  | number | row_number 
--------+--------+------------
 john   |      1 |          1
 jessy  |      2 |          2
 darine |      3 |          3
 prince |      5 |          4
 queeny |      7 |          5

UPDATE foo SET number = nums.row_number
FROM (
    SELECT name, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY number) FROM foo
) nums
WHERE foo.name = nums.name;

postgres=# SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY number;
  name  | number 
--------+--------
 john   |      1
 jessy  |      2
 darine |      3
 prince |      4
 queeny |      5
```

Comment: This would work fine in postgresql but won't work in mysql. I have posted query for mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using **MYSQL** database. Try below query.

```
UPDATE students 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT name, @num:=@num+1 row_number FROM students, (SELECT @num:=0) n
) nums
SET number = nums.row_number
WHERE students.name = nums.name;
```

If you have primary key in your table then replace `WHERE students.name = nums.name` with your primary key as name can have duplicate value.